# .NET MVC UK date format won't validate despite culture en-GB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, locale

I have a series of web forms in MVC. After some updates to the website recently the DateTime field validation is assuming dates are in US format and therefore days greater than 12 are failing validation, despite the fact that I've specifed the edit date format, the validation code and the culture as en-GB. Tried various browsers, all with language set as English (United Kingdom) and validation fails in Firefox, Chrome and Edge, and only works in IE. Tried various other suggestions found here including ModelBinding but nothing seems to work.

In the class:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

In web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

In global.asax:

```
CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

In jquery.validate.js:

```
date: function (value, element) {
        $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
        var date = Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB");
        return this.optional(element) || 
                       !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date).toString());
    }
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: In global.asax, what is the point of `newCulture`? It is overridden 2 lines later.

Comment: @kiziu, I was desperately trying every suggestion I came across!

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work correctly with MVC 5. There were two changes needed:

1. To add a model binder, as the default binder does not take into account the CurrentUICulture. I did this with client validation removed just to test it. The reason why it doesn't by default is you might use dates in URL's, although I think if I did I would want to format the URL along yyyy-mm-dd lines.
2. To alter the client validation to take into account UK dates. I am not sure your jquery.validate.js code would work. I also had a bit of trouble with this as well, so in the end I installed nuget package jQuery.Validation.AdditionalMethods and made code that used that.

My own blog post at http://www.ablogaboutcoding.com/2017/08/12/mvc-uk-date-issues/ explains further.